# Would like to have equal widths for my flex item buttons, but not sizing at all

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to size the Sure and Cancel buttons to be the same size. I placed them in a flexbox container with `display: flex`. Then, I put flex: 1 for `.button.sure` and `.button.cancel`, but the flex items are not responding at all.

I am working on the assumption that putting `display: flex` on the container and then its flex items with `flex: 1`, should do the trick, but I have no idea why these items aren't responding.

I thought maybe the button tags were causing an error with the `flex: 1` declaration, so tried nesting the `<button>` in `<div>` and that didn't work too.

Here is what I have:

```css
.icon {
 background-color: lavender;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: royalblue;
}

.prompt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttonbox {
  display: flex;
  background: lavender;
}

.button{ 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.button.sure {
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
}

.button.cancel {
  background: white;
  color: royalblue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="prompt">  
  <div class="icon">!</div>
  <div class="buttonbox"> 
    <button class="button sure">Sure</button>
    <button class="button cancel">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex: 1` just means that the flex child can grow if it needs to (shorthand for `flex: 1 0 0`; see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)). Not sure where you got the idea that it would make things the same size.

Comment: Probably from here (see method 1) but it's got some caveats https://css-tricks.com/equal-columns-with-flexbox-its-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

Comment: Flex 1 works if you put a width on your parent container e.g. .buttonbox witdh: 20ch will make both fill to equal size. If not then the flex container will shrink to the contents which is the default behaviour. The issue is that the flex box doesn't know how the size one element from the size of the other. Best use grid with grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr

Comment: @HereticMonkey Could you not place `flex:1` to the child elements so that they will have an even amount of space allocated to them? Also in that document I am seeing that it says `flex: 1` is `flex: 1 1 0`.

Comment: I've popped an answer in below using grid for you

Comment: What @Adam said. From that link: "One-value syntax: the value must be one of:
a valid value for `<flex-grow>`: then the shorthand expands to `flex: <flex-grow> 1 0`." `flex: 1` provides a valid value for `<flex-grow>`, so it expands to `flex: 1 1 0`. In other words, you're right, I'm wrong, it's early where I live and I haven't had my coffee yet :).

Comment: Coffee is the lifeblood of every developer :-D

Comment: @HereticMonkey No worries! Thanks for the clarification. And I was on my third cup of coffee anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your flexbox with grid. If you set the grid-template-columns to 1fr then each child will occupy the same size. More info on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and there's a nice video from [Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU)

```css
.icon {
 background-color: lavender;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: royalblue;
}

.prompt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttonbox {
  /*replaced flex with grid */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background: lavender;
}

.button{ 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.button.sure {
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
  /*flex: 1; delete this, not needed*/
}

.button.cancel {
  background: white;
  color: royalblue;
  /*flex: 1; delete this, not needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="prompt">  
  <div class="icon">!</div>
  <div class="buttonbox"> 
    <button class="button sure">Sure</button>
    <button class="button cancel">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I learn grid, I will definitely reference this. Thanks so much! Also, I tried the setting a width of 100% to the parent element of the button box and the Sure and Cancel buttons worked as intended with `flex:1`. They are both the same size, but the 100% width is making them very wide, which is something I can tinker around with to get an intended size. Thanks a lot, again! @Adam

Comment: If you know the number of characters in both buttons then just set the width to a fixed pixel size or use rem of ch units

Comment: If this answer meets your needs can you mark it as accepted please?